# How do I show the result on same page after submitting the form?

Tags: forms, 8

How do I show the result on same page after submitting the form in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 6):

Request a rebuild in `submitForm()` and then display the result in `buildForm()`:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  // build form

  if ($form_state->isRebuilding()) {

    // display result

  }
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form_state->setRebuild();

}
```

Comment: Doesn't get much simpler than this.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a tutorial to explain how to do this: https://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/drupal-form-api-ajax-form-and-results-same-page

Comment: Amazing.  Thank you.  Drupal needs much more of this.